# HTTP Request with Python 2.7.3

Tags: http, python-2.7, httprequest, urllib, urlopen

I have a string result in this string is the **URL www.test.com**

I know that on www.test.com is an website with the number **4**. I will save the number in my programm as an integer.

```
import urllib
giveTheInt = [urllib.urlopen(url)]
```

But i receive only:

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out.
```

The wireless it's ok, I have a connection to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib

url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
fp = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = fp.read()
n = int(data)
giveTheInt = [n]
print(giveTheInt)
```

You should test that you can ping your whatever.com.
If you can't ping it, that may be why you have an error.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is `urllib2`, but I saw your post and this worked for me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://ron-swanson-quotes.herokuapp.com/v2/quotes')
# print response.info()
data = response.read()
print data
response.close()  # best practice to close the file
```

Taken from [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/how-to-use-urllib2-in-python/).